# Edit an answer to make a correction, or post a new answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

So I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38093394/6340326) earlier today, and within my answer there was a flaw in that a counter was kept in the wrong place and would result in an infinite loop. This was overlooked as I submitted my answer and I realised the fault as another user pointed it out as a response to my answer.

I was about to edit [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38093748/6340326) to correct the fault, when I noticed the other user had actually [posted a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38093868/6340326) of their own, essentially the same as mine just with the issue corrected.

At this point I would have just deleted my answer, but as I'm fairly new to SO I'm wondering what the correct way to approach a situation like this is? Was the other user correct to post a new answer, or should they have edited my answer / gave me chance to edit it myself?

Reading [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/6340326) suggests that answers on aging questions should be edited to correct faults, but it's unclear if this should be done on recent posts.

Answer (score 2):

If you hover over the 'answered x minutes/hours/days ago' label, you'll see the exact posting timestamp:

[image]

The other user posted his answer only 6 minutes after yours. It's entirely possible that he didn't read your answer before posting his.

You could fix your answer to make it correct, but if you think it doesn't add any value to the other answer, save yourself the trouble and delete it.

Comment: Entirely possible, I can see that would make sense. This does raise another question, when writing an answer you are prompted that other answers have been posted since starting to write your own, in this case is it correct to continue to post your answer before reviewing answers submitted just before your own?

Comment: In my experience, it is often (in more popular tag channels at least) the case, that up to 5 or even more people simultaneously work on an answer for a single question, knowing this and respecting every contribution is IMO important. The "web-version-two-nagging-to-reload" behavior is more often annoying, then helpful for me (mobile interface still, well, ...). Sometimes even comments are offered as (intermediate) answers, just because there is a need for multi line format to formulate a quest for detail ... corrections might profit from an explicit **update** comment or the like.